# Compare indexpath Of Cell with uiButton Is This Possible?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a Uibutton in one class and  Uitable in different Class...

Now i want to compare IndexPAth(Particular cell Position) with Uibutton Of Different class...

Actually i want to print Different different value on particular cell Which I am Fetching from Different Different Uibutton`s Methods from another class....

Here is My code....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}




if(indexPath == btn1){   // This is the Line What i want , i am trying this but dont go inside the condition..


UILabel  *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 5, 290, 60)];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//lbl.editable = NO;
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
//  txtView1.text= textviewstring;
// txtView1.text = @"Personal";

if([fetchFormArray222 count]<1){
lbl.text=@"";

}
else{

lbl.text = [fetchFormArray222 objectAtIndex:0];

}
//  [txtView1 setDelegate:self];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[[cell contentView] addSubview:lbl];    




}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the apple documentation of UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the button in the other class to perform a new fetch in the class you're focusing on that loads fetctFormArray222 and then reload the UITableView?

Comment: Yeah , I want to fetch Another one on the same cell in else condtion fetctFormArray333